# Trouble streaming microphone audio between devices using Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, multipeer-connectivity

I have set up the basics of Multipeer Connectivity successfully and my two devices recognize and connect to each other as peers. However, I am having trouble streaming and playing audio using `AVAudioPlayerNode`. I have a `StartRecording()` function called when a button is toggled, and it should open and close the OutputStream.

My general understanding is that you need to create an `AVAudioEngine`, attach an `AVAudioPlayerNode`, connect the `AVAudioPlayerNode` to the main mixer or output node (?). Then, from the sending device, start an `outputStream`, and `installTap()` on the Audio Engine's `inputNode`, which will continuously send the bytes converted from `AVAudioPCMBuffer`.

In the Multipeer functions, once stream data is received, I set the `ViewController`'s `inputStream` which I think is handled using the `StreamDelegate` functions. The incoming bytes should then be handled (if there is space). The code seems to be functional, but `.hasBytesAvailable` is rarely called. I have microphone access enabled on both devices too.

Since it's hard to fit all the code in this post, I have created a [public gist](https://gist.github.com/yogurtsake/5309b7422ad1ab4314da5d4948167614) with relevant files. Here are the relevant parts from 3 main classes : `ViewController.swift`, `MultipeerHandler.swift`, `StreamHelper.swift`:

In `ViewController.swift`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureAudioSession()
    audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: false)
    multipeerSetup()
    viewSetup()
}

private func configureAudioSession() {
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
        try audioSession.setMode(.voiceChat)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)

        audioSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] (allowed: Bool) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if allowed {
                    print("allowed")
                }
            }
        }
    } catch { }
}

@objc func startRecording() throws {
    // start streaming
    if !(self.isRecording) {
        audioEngine.stop()
        let inputFormat = inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)

        audioEngine.attach(audioPlayer)
        audioEngine.connect(audioPlayer, to: mainMixer, format: audioFormat)
        // audioEngine.connect(audioPlayer, to: audioPlayer.outputNode, format: inputFormat)

        do {
            if multipeerHandler.session.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
                if outputStream != nil {
                    outputStream = nil
                }

                outputStream = try multipeerHandler.session.startStream(withName: "voice", toPeer: multipeerHandler.session.connectedPeers[0])
                outputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode: .default)
                outputStream.delegate = self
                outputStream.open()

                inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(inputFormat.sampleRate/10), format: inputFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in

                    let convertedFrameCount = AVAudioFrameCount((Double(buffer.frameLength) / inputFormat.sampleRate) * inputFormat.sampleRate)
                    guard let pcmBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: inputFormat, frameCapacity: convertedFrameCount) else {
                        print("cannot make pcm buffer")
                        return
                    }

                    print("\(#line)")

                    let bytes = StreamHelper.copyAudioBufferBytes(pcmBuffer)
                    if(self.outputStream.hasSpaceAvailable){
                        self.outputStream.write(bytes, maxLength: bytes.count)
                        print("\(#line)")
                    }
                }
                audioEngine.prepare()
                try audioEngine.start()

            } else {
                print("no peers to connect to")
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }
        self.isRecording = true
    } else {
        // stop streaming
        inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        self.isRecording = false
    }
}
```

In `MultipeerHelper.swift`:

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    print("didReceiveStream")
    if streamName == "voice" {
        print(#line)
        viewController.inputStream = stream
        viewController.inputStream.delegate = viewController
        viewController.inputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode: .default)
        viewController.inputStream.open()
    }
}
```

Also, it is important to note that I have found a lot of similar posts but they're somewhat old. Here are some of the sources I used to understand what's going on:

- https://github.com/nullforlife/Multipeer-Voice-Chat/blob/master/Multipeer%20Voice%20Chat/ViewController.swift
- [Playing an audio file repeatedly with AVAudioEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518863/playing-an-audio-file-repeatedly-with-avaudioengine)
- [Trouble hooking up AVAudioUnitEffect with AVAudioEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443863/trouble-hooking-up-avaudiouniteffect-with-avaudioengine)
- [AVAudioPlayerNode doesn't play sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958750/avaudioplayernode-doesnt-play-sound)
- [AVAudioEngine inputNode's format changes when playing an AVAudioPlayerNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903563/avaudioengine-inputnodes-format-changes-when-playing-an-avaudioplayernode)

Once again, I have posted a [public gist](https://gist.github.com/yogurtsake/5309b7422ad1ab4314da5d4948167614) for this inquiry. Any help would be greatly appreciated.